# How to add new colums to Robot Framework HTML report

Tags: robotframework

I want to be able to add more columns to the report.html file generated by Robot Framework and specifically and specifically into "Test Details"/Suites Tab ( see example here http://robotframework.org/QuickStartGuide/report.html#suites?s1).

Additionally would be nice to have some special keywords in . robot file to control the content of that column, like it is currently available for the "Documentation" column.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no support for what you want. Your only option is to directly modify the source code. If you know how to do that, you can obviously add any features you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new metrics report release thanks to adiralashiva8.

The metrics provide more information including graphs.

This could be an alternative for your problem.

It also supports email report sending.

This is how the report looks like.

[image]

You can find all the information here.

[New Report](https://github.com/adiralashiva8/robotframework-metrics)